# Remove every special character except hyphen

Tags: java, string, replace, split, formatting

I have two Strings, for example "Stack Overflow" and "Stack-Overflow".
Now I am working on a String matching method and I need to format some strings.

Every special character should be the end of a String, except the hyphen. So "Stack Overflow" would become "Stack" and "Stack-Overflow" would stay the same.

I already used `str.split(" ", 1)[0];`, `str.replaceAll("\\s", "")` and `str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");` but It doesn't cooperate with the hyphen.

What replacement method should I use?

Comment: Did you assigned it? Strings are immutable in Java (`replaceAll` **returns** a String and doesn't change the current one).

Comment: I'm aware of that. Yes, all my Strings are assigned.

Comment: Can you post a **SSCCE**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `[^\\w-]+` regex

```
    String str = "Stack-Overflow";
    String str2 = str.split("[^\\w-]+")[0];     
    System.out.println(str2);
```

For: `Stack-Overflow` Output `Stack-Overflow`

For: `Stack Overflow` Output `Stack`

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to do it in C# using Regular expression

```
string regex = "[^a-zA-Z0-9-]";
var s3 = Regex.Split(inputString, regex)[0];
```

You can implement a similar type of code in Java also.

Answer (score 0):

`.split("\\W")[0]` seems to be working.

This

```
  System.out.println("Hello-World".split("\\W")[0]);
```

just prints "Hello" from here, and

```
  System.out.println("Hello World".split("\\W")[0]);
```

does the same, while

```
  System.out.println("Hello123123orld".split("\\W")[0]);
```

prints "Hello123123orld", as you would expect.